# Calculating Repayment Rate Using Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2010

**Goal**: Considering the date of disbursement cohort, I need the month with the lowest repayment rate in 2018 (loans repaid on time)? Using pivot table

| id | principal_disbursed | principal_repaid | due_date | repayment_date | credit_officer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | $334 | $334 | 12/10/2017 | 17/10/2017 | John |
| 2 | $184 | $184 | 10/11/2018 | 20/10/2018 | Maria |
| 3 | $417 | $417 | 18/08/2017 | 24/08/2017 | Maria |
| 4 | $500 | $500 | 04/08/2017 | 14/07/2017 | Maria |
| 5 | $250 | $250 | 04/08/2017 | 06/08/2017 | John |
| 6 | $250 | $250 | 02/08/2017 | 24/07/2017 | Frank |
| 7 | $500 | $500 | 04/08/2017 | 12/08/2017 | John |
| 8 | $417 | $417 | 10/08/2017 | 08/08/2017 | Maria |
| 9 | $334 | $334 | 05/08/2017 | 09/08/2017 | Frank |
| 10 | $500 | $500 | 01/08/2017 | 05/08/2017 | Maria |
| 11 | $400 | $400 | 08/08/2017 | 10/08/2017 | Frank |
| 12 | $500 | $500 | 10/08/2017 | 29/07/2017 | Frank |
| 13 | $500 | $500 | 10/08/2017 | 14/08/2017 | John |
| 14 | $500 | $500 | 12/08/2017 | 30/07/2017 | Frank |
| 15 | $484 | $484 | 04/08/2017 | 07/08/2017 | Maria |
| 16 | $167 | $167 | 13/08/2017 | 14/08/2017 | Frank |
| 17 | $334 | $334 | 09/08/2017 | 22/08/2017 | John |
| 18 | $450 | $450 | 06/09/2017 | 05/09/2017 | Maria |
| 19 | $500 | $500 | 09/09/2017 | 17/09/2017 | Maddy |
| 20 | $250 | $250 | 23/08/2017 | 16/08/2017 | John |
| 21 | $250 | $250 | 07/09/2017 | 16/08/2017 | Frank |
| 22 | $167 | $167 | 10/09/2017 | 12/09/2017 | Maria |
| 23 | $500 | $500 | 15/08/2017 | 17/08/2017 | Maria |
| 24 | $250 | $250 | 12/08/2017 | 06/09/2017 | Frank |
| 25 | $500 | $500 | 13/08/2017 | 19/08/2017 | Maria |
| 26 | $250 | $250 | 13/09/2017 | 21/08/2017 | Maria |
| 27 | $250 | $250 | 14/09/2017 | 03/09/2017 | Frank |
| 28 | $500 | $500 | 16/09/2017 | 06/09/2017 | John |

Comment: So can you clarify what the result should be for that dataset, and why?

Comment: I need just the month with the lowest repayment rate in 2018 (loans repaid on time).
Is this clear enough

Comment: I know what you require. I'd like you to tell me what your manually calculated expected result for the dataset you posted is, so that I can know if the logic I develop is correct or not.

Comment: The expected output should be a list of repayment rate for all the month in 2018. Then I will be able to get the month with the lowest rate. 

Final answer should be like... AUGUST  if that is the month with the lowest rate

Comment: Suggest you repost a smaller dataset for which you ARE able to determine manually the month with the lowest rate. And explain what logic you used to arrive at your answer.